# Check if two objects are equal React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object

Can you help me on how to check if object the two objects are equal? here's the two objects that I'm trying to compare...

```
let obj1 = {"Add Ons": [{"addon_id": 32, "addon_name": "Black Pearl", "addon_price": 15}, {"addon_id": 33, "addon_name": "White Pearl", "addon_price": 15}]}
let obj2 = {"Add Ons": [{"addon_id": 33, "addon_name": "White Pearl", "addon_price": 15}, {"addon_id": 32, "addon_name": "Black Pearl", "addon_price": 15}]}
```

I tried using this `const isEqual = (...objects) => objects.every(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(objects[0]));` to check if it's equal but if the array inside is shuffle it returns false. how to check if it's equal event though in random? thank you so much!

Comment: How do you identify 2 objects are different? I mean which property we can use? All of it? if any value is different it's not the same? If the same `addon_id` is present in both arrays, can we call it equal?

Comment: You can use [_isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) from `lodash` for your comparison and check another methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) if you want. But I'll prefer to use `_isEqual`.

Comment: I advise to see these questions:

First: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)


Second: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects/16788517#16788517)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are checking for equality of `addon_id`,

1. You can get the arrays like obj1['Add Ons']
2. If the length of arrays is not the same then they are not equal.
3. Check for all objects in the first array with `every()` and check whether the `obj2` array contains all of the ids.

```
    function isEqual() {
    let obj1 = {
      'Add Ons': [
        { addon_id: 32, addon_name: 'Black Pearl', addon_price: 15 },
        { addon_id: 33, addon_name: 'White Pearl', addon_price: 15 }
      ]
    };
    let obj2 = {
      'Add Ons': [
        { addon_id: 33, addon_name: 'White Pearl', addon_price: 15 },
        { addon_id: 32, addon_name: 'Black Pearl', addon_price: 15 },
        { addon_id: 34, addon_name: 'Black Pearl', addon_price: 15 }
      ]
    };

    if (obj1['Add Ons'].length !== obj2['Add Ons']) return false;
    return obj1['Add Ons'].every(val => {
      return obj2['Add Ons'].some(b2 => b2.addon_id === val.addon_id);
    });
  }
```